# How to show a DataTemplate in the window

Tags: wpf, datatemplate

I have declared a DataTemplate in Window.Resources; I don't intend to use it inside an ItemsControl, but rather just use it as a user control. How do I put it on a form?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put a [ContentControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentcontrol.aspx) into your user control, and set its `ContentTemplate` to your `DataTemplate`.

```
<ContentControl ContentTemplate="{StaticResource keyOfDataTemplate}"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using MVVM, and want to display the DataTemplate in response to a property on your ViewModel, you can use:

```
<ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Data}"/>
```

Where Data is a property of the type you registered the DataTemplate with.